# PHP - What does return -1 mean?

Tags: php

I know that 1 represents true, and 0 represents false. What would this code mean:

```
return -1;
```

Is this the same as return TRUE?

Comment: No, it is not the same. There exist other values besides TRUE and FALSE.

Comment: Depends entirely on context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On boolean terms, everything that is not an empty string, `NULL`, `array()`, `false`, `0`, `"0"`, and undefined is `true` (`-1` included). Everything else is `false`.

See [Here](http://php.net/manual/it/types.comparisons.php), the table "*Comparisons of $x with PHP functions*".

Answer (score 1):

It represents `-1` and nothing else. What we're missing here to tell you what it means is the context of its use. For example, `-1` could be used to say nothing was found such as with arrays (since arrays have `0` as an index).

If you were to evaluate `-1`, does not come out to `false`. it comes out to `true`.

`var_dump((bool) -1); // bool(true)`

Comment: Note that it's perfect possible to have an array with an index value of `-1`.... `$x = array(-1 => 'Hello World');`

Comment: @MarkBaker Indeed it is, which plays into my initial statement that without some form of context the meaning of `-1` could really be anything.